# Remove last x elements from the list

Tags: c#, list

Lets say I have a `List<Car> Cars` that have n items and I want to delete the last two. The best way that I found is:

`Cars.RemoveRange(Cars.Count-2, 2);`

Is there better way? I searching something like this:

`Cars.RemoveFrom(Cars.Count-2); //pseudocode`

Comment: `Count - 1` is the last element, `Count - 2` is the second to last. It was correct `Count - 2`

Comment: @xanatos Yes! you're absolutely right.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No, there isn't... But if you want you can put it in an extension method.

```
static class ListEx
{
    public static void RemoveFrom<T>(this List<T> lst, int from)
    {
        lst.RemoveRange(from, lst.Count - from);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Now we have the option

```
void List<T>.RemoveRange(int index, int count);
```

See [Microsoft Docs List.RemoveRange(Int32, Int32) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.removerange?view=netcore-3.1) for Core

[Microsoft Docs List.RemoveRange(Int32, Int32) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.removerange?view=netframework-4.8) for Framework 4.8

**Applies To**

.NET Core
3.1 3.0 2.2 2.1 2.0 1.1 1.0

.NET Framework
4.8 4.7.2 4.7.1 4.7 4.6.2 4.6.1 4.6 4.5.2 4.5.1 4.5 4.0 3.5 3.0 2.0

.NET Standard
2.1 2.0 1.6 1.4 1.3 1.2 1.1 1.0